# Не удается открыть Windows Form для редактирования в Visual Studio

Tags: c++, winforms, visual-studio

Не получается открыть MyForm.h для редактирования параметров. Погуглил как можно исправить, нужно было в файл MyForm.cpp добавить код:

```
#include "MyForm.h"

using namespace System;
using namespace System::Windows::Forms;

[STAThreadAttribute]
void Main(array<String^>^ args) {
Application::EnableVisualStyles();
Application::SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
DataStudents::MyForm form;
Application::Run(% form);
}
```

После добавления данного кода, форма начала открыватся при запуске программы, но сама форма все также не открывается для редактирования, и появилось вот такое предупреждение:
[image: errormyform.h]

Как это можно исправить? Спасибо

UPD. фото стек-трейса
[image: stacktrace]

Экземпляры ошибки (1)

в System.ComponentModel.Design.Serialization.CodeDomDesignerLoader.EnsureDocument(IDesignerSerializationManager manager)
в System.ComponentModel.Design.Serialization.CodeDomDesignerLoader.PerformLoad(IDesignerSerializationManager manager)
в Microsoft.VisualStudio.Design.Serialization.CodeDom.VSCodeDomDesignerLoader.PerformLoad(IDesignerSerializationManager serializationManager)
--- Конец трассировка стека из предыдущего расположения, где возникло исключение ---
в Microsoft.VisualStudio.Design.Serialization.CodeDom.VSCodeDomDesignerLoader.PerformLoad(IDesignerSerializationManager serializationManager)
в Microsoft.VisualStudio.Design.Serialization.CodeDom.VSCodeDomDesignerLoader.DeferredLoadHandler.Microsoft.VisualStudio.TextManager.Interop.IVsTextBufferDataEvents.OnLoadCompleted(Int32 fReload)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Скорее всего, у Вас внутри конструктора в MyForm написано что то, что не может "переварить" дизайнер. Например, Вы обращаетесь там к базе данных, и при этом возникает ошибка. На той картинке, котрую Вы приложили - есть олтчная кнопочка, котрая показывает стек трейс - то есть, фактически, скажет Вам, в какой строчке происходит ошибка. Нажмите на эту ссылку, если будет что то непонятно - прикрепте стек трейс и код самой программы к вопросу.

**Дополнение**

Спасибо, что добавили код исключения и картинку с развернутым стектрейсом.

К сожалению, понятнее пока не стало.

Видно, что что студия не может загрузить что то в дизайнер форм.

*Обычно* такое происходит, когда в форме написано что то, что дизайнер не может интерпретировать при рендеринге формы.

Так как ошибка по прежнему остаётся непонятной (кода, который есть в форме, в Вашем ответе то нет) - то советую начать с чистого листа: создать новую форму, пустую, которая будет нормально открываться в дизайнере форм.

А потом перенести в неё все элементы с той формы, которая в дизайнере не открывается. При этом при переносе каждого элемента - пробуйте заново открыть новую форму в дизайнере. Как только она перестанет открывться - всё, Вы поймали свою ошибку!

Comment: Фото и код добавил